# Backwards compatibility for 7.1 applications running in MobileFirst 8.0 server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

In version 7.1 of MobileFirst it supported a limited backward compatibility to allow us to run 6.3 apps against the 7.1 MobileFirst Server.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_compat.html

Is this possible with MobileFirst 8.0?  Can we run 7.1 apps against the MobileFirst 8.0 server.  It seems from the documentation like you are forced to migrate your apps, project, and adapters from 7.1 to 8.0 before they can be deployed and run on the MobileFirst 8.0 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible with MobileFirst 8.0? Can we run 7.1 apps against the MobileFirst 8.0 server. It seems from the documentation like you are forced to migrate your apps, project, and adapters from 7.1 to 8.0 before they can be deployed and run on the MobileFirst 8.0 server.

No backwards compatibility.

Learn more here:

- What's new: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/release-notes/whats-new/
- Migrating: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/